# How do I precompile Python code on a Mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using a Mac M2 with Ventura, and the answers I can get from other webpages / ChatGPT / Bard told me I can do either:

1. Run this as a python program, using `python3 do_it_foo.py`

```py
import py_compile
py_compile.compile('abc.py')
```

2. Or, in Bash, do

```bash
python3 -m py_compile abc.py
```

and a `abc.pyc` should be created. And then just run `python3 abc.pyc`

But none of the methods above can produce `.pyc` file and running it shows:

```bash
$ python3 abc.pyc
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3: can't open file
'/Users/peterpeter/try/TryHowLong/abc.pyc': [Errno 2] No such file
or directory
```

How can it be done?

Comment: For starters, if you use `py_compile` the cached bytecode files will be put in `__pycache__` in the current working directory, just like if you had done `python abc.py` (since running a script once will cache the bytecode) so you probably want `python __pycache__/abc.cpython-311.pyc` (the version information might be differet)

Comment: rather, not the current working directory, but in a specific directory relative to the source-code file. In any case, [the docs give an example](https://docs.python.org/3/library/py_compile.html): "For example, if file is /foo/bar/baz.py cfile will default to /foo/bar/__pycache__/baz.cpython-32.pyc"

Comment: there is no such `__pycache__` folder in the current directory, and I even did an `ls -al` to see any `.` files or folders and there is no such thing